# How do I convert each array in the nested arrays as rows in the data-frames?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, multidimensional-array

I would like to convert each individual array in the nested arrays as each rows in the dataframes. For example: The nested arrays example is below. How do I create each numbers inside [[... ]] in rows in dataframe? There are many nested arrays such as below. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
Just to make things easier, I want to create each array as rows in dataframe. Example for the first array needs to be laid out like this in dataframe
***-0.14091441,  0.02556057,  0.10425788, ..., -0.03699904, 0.00503982,  0.08761989**
So far I have tried :

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(arrays_list[i][0]) for i in range(len(arrays_list))]).reset_index(drop=False)
```

arrays_list being my nested arrays.

```
[array([[[-0.14091441,  0.02556057,  0.10425788, ..., -0.03699904,
       0.00503982,  0.08761989]],

    [[-0.16227441,  0.03150389,  0.06440173, ..., -0.10543424,
       0.05987305,  0.04117104]],

    [[-0.11423473,  0.03741207,  0.0783961 , ..., -0.16773996,
       0.06566695,  0.0683976 ]],

    ...,

    [[-0.13789459,  0.05840103,  0.09803487, ..., -0.09256409,
       0.01833008,  0.08413954]],

    [[-0.12652887,  0.03683193,  0.06100509, ..., -0.06188103,
       0.00915053,  0.09518969]],

    [[-0.19781192,  0.05750425,  0.14811654, ..., -0.10550601,
       0.05405622,  0.13771409]]]),

 array([[[-0.0375578 ,  0.16006446,  0.07978896, ..., -0.0883253 ,
       0.0057608 ,  0.07953031]],

    [[ 0.00282089,  0.18854009,  0.01686837, ..., -0.02981209,
      -0.01220972,  0.02810074]],

    [[ 0.0333602 ,  0.21895081,  0.05255894, ..., -0.01882036,
      -0.03316848,  0.02506595]],

    ...,

    [[-0.02498044,  0.17067145,  0.03956907, ..., -0.00617604,
       0.01254308,  0.03375499]],

    [[ 0.0333602 ,  0.21895081,  0.05255894, ..., -0.01882036,
      -0.03316848,  0.02506595]],

    [[ 0.01105822,  0.20526624,  0.05087842, ..., -0.0442748 ,
      -0.08184794,  0.04356682]]]),
 array([[[-1.16298698e-01,  6.60857707e-02,  4.37349118e-02, ...,
       5.65935597e-02,  1.17720775e-01,  4.68457118e-02]],

    [[-1.70329705e-01,  7.15664029e-02,  2.13463139e-02, ...,
       8.40441436e-02,  3.38792875e-02, -9.66352411e-04]],

    [[-1.38925180e-01,  6.48617744e-02,  7.50765130e-02, ...,
       3.60708833e-02,  9.37591046e-02,  3.88324559e-02]],

    ...,

    [[-1.38925180e-01,  6.48617744e-02,  7.50765130e-02, ...,
       3.60708833e-02,  9.37591046e-02,  3.88324559e-02]],

    [[-1.55961111e-01,  7.59401619e-02,  3.65645029e-02, ...,
       9.78165418e-02,  9.37420279e-02,  5.14532737e-02]],

    [[-1.19004108e-01,  6.59743100e-02,  7.72421211e-02, ...,
       4.89978008e-02,  1.33881345e-04,  2.18758285e-02]]])]
```

---

For the purpose of this question here is an analogous mre.

```
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng()

a = rng.integers(0,5,(6,1,6))
b = rng.integers(0,5,(6,1,6))
c = rng.integers(0,5,(6,1,6))
# or just
# np.random.randint(0,5,(6,1,6))
obj = [a,b,c]
```

Comment: what are the shapes of your arrays? Can you provide some code which generates similar (smaller) arrays as well as your expected dataframe result?

Comment: I have edited the post. Can you please have a look

Comment: @user32882 - It is a list of three arrays with shapes of (x,1,y).

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question.  Sometimes you might want to create fake data for the question - as long as it faithfully represents the actual data.. The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - Please read [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the reproducible example you've provided, and assuming you want one dataframe as a result (a, b and c have same shapes).

I would first stack vertically using **numpy.stack()** all the arrays in the list of arrays as one array.

Then I would drop the middle dimension of shape 1, by slicing it out.

Then I call **pandas.DataFrame()** constructor and you should have your result.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(obj)[:,0,:])
```

Comment: [numpy.squeeze](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html#numpy.squeeze) for the xtra dimension also works.